# Laravel 6 and Vue.js update record from child component using vue-router and axios

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I have been stuck on update method using Vue Components for over a week. The update happens after a user clicks the "update" button, opening a modal. From the modal, the child component value is updating but I can't get the data to send to the DB (MySQL). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Component:

```
<tbody>
<tr v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
    <th>{{ post.name }}\</th>
    <th>{{ post.email }}</th>
    <th>{{ post.notes }}</th>
    <th>{{ post.id }}</th>
    <th>

        <button class="" v-on:click="deleteGroup(post)">
            <eva-icon name="trash-2" animation="pulse" fill="gray"></eva-icon>
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" :data-target="'#exampleModal' + post.id">
            <eva-icon name="edit-2" animation="pulse" fill="gray"></eva-icon>
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" :id="'exampleModal' + post.id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
             aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <form @submit.prevent="editGroup(post)">
                        <div class="container shadow p-4">

                            <input type="hidden" v-model="post.id"/>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="group-name">Group Name</label>
                                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" v-model="post.name" placeholder="Enter the Group Name"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Send invite Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" v-model="post.email" placeholder="Enter the email"/>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="group-image">Group Image</label>
                                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="image">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="group-notes">Notes</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" name="notes" v-model="post.notes" rows="7"></textarea>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" @click="update(post)">
                                    Save
                                </button>

                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </th>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

SCRIPT:

```
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted.')
    },

    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
        }
    },

    created() {
        this.getGroups();
    },

    methods: {

        getGroups() {
            axios.get('/groups')
                .then(response => this.posts = response.data);
        },

        deleteGroup: function (post) {
            var url = 'groups/' + post.id;
            axios.delete(url).then(response => {
                this.getGroups();
            });
        },

        editGroup: function (post) {
            var url = 'groups/' + post.id;
            axios.get(url).then(response => {
                this.getGroups();
            });
        },

        update: function (post) {
            var url = 'groups/' + post.id;
            axios.put(url).then(response => {
                this.getGroups();
            });
        }
    },
}
```

Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $post = Group::findOrFail($id);
    $post->name = $request->name;
    $post->email = $request->email;
    $post->notes = $request->notes;

    $post->save();

    return $post;
}
```

UPDATE: In case there was any confusion, I am hitting the correct route and function but can't pass the updated information causing an SQL error that fields can't be null.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Have you checked the network tab to make sure it's going to the correct route?

Comment: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/1 500 (Internal Server Error) is the error I get in the console

Comment: Route::resource('/groups', 'GroupController'); is my route

Comment: It looks like you are submitting via `<form @submit.prevent="editGroup(post)">` and     `<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" @click="update(post)">
                                    Save
                                </button>` at the same time. I believe you should submit either via form or via button, but not both at the same time

Comment: correct, however, i can only update the component on front end. I can't get the update to send to the controller. Keeps saying the data fields are empty.....

Comment: it is also your v-model should be `v-model="posts.notes"` instead of `v-model="post.notes"` or you could change `posts: []` to `post:[]`, the reason is that you're binding post data that is not defined.

Comment: changing the v-model to "posts.name" instead of "post.name" doesnt show the existing values in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're not submitting any data to your route.

```
update: function (post) {
    var url = 'groups/' + post.id;
    axios.put(url).then(response => {
         this.getGroups();
    });
}
```

You're not supplying the values of the `post` variable to your axios call. You need to add the object you are sending as the second parameter to your `put(...)` call.

```
axios.put(url, post).then(response => {
    this.getGroups();
});
```

**Edit:** Be sure you validate your data when it arrives!